# Displaying Java code in LaTeX using a monospace font

Tags: code, java

I found [this pretty template](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276843/remove-horizontal-lines-above-and-below-the-code-listings-package) to display Java code with LaTeX.
It works fine, expect for the fact that blanks do not seem to have the same width as letters.
Therefore code that is indented is not in line with the rest of the code.

What could be done to this template to fix the issue?

```
\RequirePackage{color}

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  tabsize=3
}
```

Comment: `columns=flexible,`

Comment: Thank you, I got it! :)